# How to make stone fireplace look better, darker and shinier?

Tags: paint, fireplace, sealer

My fireplace looks somewhat dull and cement-y. I would love to hear more suggestions to make the stones look better. I am thinking about putting some clear coat to make it darker and shinier. Is that a good idea? What coating do I use?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't natural stone usually flat, dull, non-reflective? If you coat the stone, then you could get a strange appearance and have to make a considerable effort to reverse what you've done.

Comment: How to make something look better is a subjective question.  I rather like the look myself.

Comment: If you must make it darker, then you must make it lighter first by throughly cleaning.  Once clean if the color must be changed use stain to darken.  Then if you really want “shinier” (in nature stone is not shiny) add a shiny clear sealer.  For what it’s worth, if you get it cleaner and brighter, that’s probably the look your going for.  You think darker and shiner but probably meaner cleaner and brighter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, cleaning then sealing can give you a shinier appearance. I emphasize the clean, since 90% of people skip that step. The sealers tend to give a wet stone look. It might not be darker but could bring out colors that your not seeing. So clean it, and see how it look wets first. Apply sealer as needed.

Comment: I would agree with cleaning and sealing. I have sand blasted and co2 blasted both brick and rock in the past c02 worked quite well without removing much material but was quite expensive, sand blasting is messy but will remove a layer so it can make it look lighter , what out for streaks or lines with sand blasting , chrushed walnut is in between on cost and and removal rate.

Comment: Blasting is the pinnacle of cleaning. Mild soap and elbow grease does wonders for most projects..